# How to horizontally align `<div>`s side by side?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, text-alignment

I have two divs, side by side, where one (right) has more content that the other (left). I've been trying to have the left one, horizontally align with the right one, so they both can be on one line. Like the drawing below.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.allinside {
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.profile_part {
  background-color: #a7f996;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 18%;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.mid_part {
  background-color: #a7f996;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.textinside {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="allinside">
  <div class="profile_part">
    <img id="mimi" src="img/profilepic.gif" alt="Maria" />
    <p class="textinside">Maria's choices</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mid_part">
    <h2>The last book I read:</h2>
    <img src="img/bravenewworld.jpg" alt="Brave new world" />
    <p class="textinside">SOME TEXT INSIDE</p>
    <h2>My favourite book:</h2>
    <img src="img/searchformeaning.jpg" alt="Man's search for meaning" />
    <p class="textinside">SOME TEXT INSIDE</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Seems to do the job, if you don't want the items to stretch, you need to override the default behavior `align-items:flex-start;` on the container `.allinside`

Comment: try for .profile_part {align-self: flex-start;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting to know the `display` types might help(inline, inline-block, block, flex)
Here, the `flex` at the parent is causing the elements to stretch.
Try `inline-block`

```css
.allinside{
}

.profile_part{
    background-color: #a7f996;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 18%;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;

}

.mid_part{
    background-color: #a7f996;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    display:inline-block;

}


.textinside{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set

```
.allinside {
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
}
.profile-part, .mid-part {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```